# Can not mount project web app database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

I have 2 A and B server one production and one for development
I want to mount server A ProjectWebApp database to server B

but it gives error

```
Mount-SPProjectWebInstance -SiteCollection http://server/PWA -DatabaseName ProjectWebApp
```

[image]

Comment: Makesure db name is correct n ur account having proper permission, also make sure no other operation going on db....maybe u kill all connection from db.

Comment: No my account hase db owner permission but it is not working

Comment: For other project web app databases when I backup and restore it to the another server it works, but ProjectWebApp not working